# How to select certain fix column in multiple pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I try to select certain columns (fix) column in multiple dataframe (`Y_1`,`Y_2`, ... , `Y_100`). This is what I've tried

```
X_1 = Y_1[['name','address','target','achievement']]
X_2 = Y_2[['name','address','target','achievement']]

X_100 = Y_100[['name','address','target','achievement']]
```

The problem is the amount of column that I select is growing, currently I do manual, but when the column I select grow, It's prone to mistake

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put that in a list:

```
cols = ['name','address','target','achievement']; 
X_1 = Y_1[cols]
...
```

Also, why don't you create a list/dict of your dataframes so you don't need to write a hundred lines of code:

```
list_dfs = [Y_1, Y_2, ..., Y_100]

cols = ['name','address','target','achievement']

list_X_dfs = [Y[cols] for Y in list_dfs]
```

Comment: `KeyError: 'cols'` on my case

Comment: It's not the constant string `'cols'`, it is the variable `cols`, without quotes.